# Codeigniter регистрация к базе SQLSRV/MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

не работает запрос к базе mssql сам Codeigniter настроен коннект есть проверял
Controller:

```
    public function register()
{

    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

        $data = array(
            'memb___id' => $_POST['login'],
            'mail_addr' => $_POST['email'],
            'memb__pwd' => $_POST['pass']

        );

        $this->db->_insert('MEMB_INFO', $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "Ваш аккаунт был зарегистрирован. Вы можете войти сейчас");
        redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
    }
    $this->load->view('register');
}
```

register.php:

```
        <form action="<?php echo base_url('home/register')?>" class="popup-input-search" method="post" >
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="input-signtype" id="login" name="login" placeholder="UserName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="input-signtype" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="input-signtype" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="input-signtype" id="re_pass" name="re_pass" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="be-checkbox">
                <label class="check-box">
                    <input class="checkbox-input" type="checkbox" required="" name="rules_verify" value="yes" > <span class="check-box-sign"></span>
                </label>
                <span class="large-popup-text">
                    Я прочитал и согласен с <a class="be-popup-terms" href="blog-detail-2.html">условия использования</a> и <a class="be-popup-terms" href="blog-detail-2.html">Политика конфиденциальности</a>.
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 for-signin">
            <button class="be-popup-sign-button" name="register">Register</button>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Успешный коннект не гарантирует возможность вставки данных в таблицу. Предлагаю проверить ответ от БД при отправке запроса, включить отладку

Comment: я выводил данные с базы через PHP а с регистрацией не правильно указал базу  
работает все с базой была проблема